# Material-ui tab indicator disappearing when clicking other tabs other than homepage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tabs

The material-ui tab indicator is not working as expected when I added the `currentUser` codes. When they were only the UI beforehand, it was working well.

```
const Header = (props) => {
  const { currentUser } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  // for the tab to stay on the correct path/page even if it was reloaded
  useEffect(() => {
    let path = window.location.pathname;
    if (path === "/" && value !== 0) setValue(0);
    else if (path === "/login" && value !== 1) setValue(1);
    else if (path === "/registration" && value !== 2) setValue(2);
    else if (path === "/profile" && value !== 2) setValue(2);
  }, [value]);


  //Breakpoints
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMatch = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"));
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar
          variant="dense">
         
          {isMatch ? (
            <h1>
              <div>
                <DrawerComponent />
              </div>
            </h1>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Grid>
                <Tabs
                  value={value}
                  indicatorColor="primary"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  aria-label="simple tabs example"
                  variant="fullWidth"
                >
                  <Tab disableRipple label="Homepage" to="/" component={Link} />
                  {currentUser && (
                    <div>
                      <Tab
                        disableRipple
                        label="Profile"
                        to="/profile"
                        component={Link}
                      />
                      <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>
                        Logout
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  )}

                  {!currentUser && (
                    <div>
                      <Tab
                        disableRipple
                        label="Login"
                        to="/login"
                        component={Link}
                      />
                      <Tab
                        disableRipple
                        label="Register"
                        to="/registration"
                        component={Link}
                      />
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Tabs>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          )}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
};

Header.defaultProps = {
  currentUser: null,
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Header);
```

Comment: Could it be `Tabs` knows what to do only with `Tab` children, but instead yours are wrapped in `div`. Seems like that's why the `Homepage` is only working fine.

Comment: I tried changing the `div` to a fragment and it still did not work

Comment: Yeah, it's the same issue with fragments - you need to directly place the `Tab` inside `Tabs`. If you'd like it to serve as button as well, try attaching the `onClick` directly to the Tab. Otherwise you could put the `Button` inside a `TabPanel`.

Comment: If I would get rid of the fragment or div, it'll cause an error since it says that `JSX expressions must have one parent element.` inside the `currentUser && [...codes here]`

Comment: Indeed, this could be avoided by having each Tab conditionally rendered eg. 
`{!currentUser && <Tab label="Login"...`
`{!currentUser && <Tab label="Register"...`

Comment: It does work, though, is there any other way around other than wrapping each tab with the `currentUser`?

Comment: Nothing much prettier I could think of. Maybe having a map of the tabs to iterate - like `tabsMap = [ { label: "Login", to: "/login", currentUser: false }, { label: "Profile", to: "/profile", currentUser: true }, ...]`. Then inside `Tabs` you do `tabsMap.map(tab => currentUser === tab.currentUser ? ( <Tab .. />) : null).`.

Comment: I did use wrapping the currentUser for every tab, however, it kind of disrupts when it comes to the Tab with the Button of log out. When clicking profile, the indicator directly goes to the Button logout, it does not stay on the profile tab